# Asset not loading on production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, assets, production

Hello stackoverflow community,

I am building a Rails application which uses devise for authentication and it works fine on development mode. And when I host the app on Heroku everything works fine but the Checkbox next the question to save the password is missing.

I am using the Metronic Admin Theme which is based on Twitter Bootstrap.

Here is the checkbox which doesn't show up on production mode.

```
  .form-actions
    .checkbox
      = f.check_box :remember_me
      = f.label :remember_me, 'Passwort merken'
```

This is my production.rb file

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  # --> nope, enabled it because we dont have no nginx!
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true
  config.assets.js_compressor  = :uglifier
  config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # change this if you want to expire all your assets
  config.assets.version = '1.0'
  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = ENV['HTTPS'].to_bool

  # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
  config.log_level = :info

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
  config.autoflush_log = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

  #Set timezone
  config.time_zone = 'Bern'

  # google analytics
  GA.tracker = ENV['GA_TRACKER']

  # mailers
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              ENV['SMPT_HOST'],
    port:                 ENV['SMPT_PORT'].to_i,
    domain:               ENV['SMPT_DOMAIN'],
    user_name:            ENV['SMPT_USER'],
    password:             ENV['SMPT_PASS'],
    authentication:       :plain,
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }


  # default host for mailer and controllers
  default_url_options = {
    host: ENV['HOST_FOR_LINKS'], protocol: config.force_ssl ? 'https://' : 'http://'
  }
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = default_url_options
  routes.default_url_options = default_url_options
end
```

and my development.rb file

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  # strong_parameters: raise exception
  config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = ENV['HTTPS'].to_bool

  # mailcatcher
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { address: "localhost", port: 1025 }

  #Set timezone
  config.time_zone = 'Bern'

  # default host for mailer and controllers
  default_url_options = {
    host: ENV['HOST_FOR_LINKS'], protocol: config.force_ssl ? 'https://' : 'http://'
  }
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = default_url_options
  routes.default_url_options = default_url_options

  # Live reload for debugging
  if ENV['LIVE_RELOAD'].to_bool
    config.middleware.use Rack::LiveReload
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you getting precompile error?? if not then its not relevant to assets...what error are you getting ???

Comment: You'll need to be more specific - a checkbox not loading won't necessarily be an asset problem

Comment: Sample site we can look at?

Comment: @Milind I am not getting a precompile error. So it probably isnt relevant to assets. But what else could it be? The error only appears when the app is hosted on heroku, on localhost the checkbox is showing up correctly